# Is the absolute Galois group of the rationals Hopfian?

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, galois-theory, profinite-groups, anabelian-geometry

Is every continuous epimorphism from the absolute Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}$ to itself injective?

Comment: A lot of relevant material is here: "Cohomology of Number Fields" Neukirch, Schmidt, Wingberg (2013) http://mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/~schmidt/NSW2e/ In particular: (12.2.3) Corollary: all automorphisms of the absolute Galois group of Q are inner; (12.3.3) Question: is every open homomorphism between absolute Galois groups of number fields injective?

Comment: @DavidLampert thank you very much for the reference to the more general question, but I was aware of it.